# Regex for allow only chars, digits with no repeating chars with length

Tags: regex

I want to create a regular expression which should satisfy below requirement.

1. a-z and A-Z allowed.
2. 0-9 allowed.
3. no special chars, no space.
4. no 2 repeating chars allowed.
5. length should be between 6-9 length.

here are some example

abcdef - allowed

abc456 - allowed

Abc685 - allowed

aabc123 - not allowed because 2 aa

sdf112 - not allowed because 2 11

aerwet2345 - not allowed because length > 9

**^(?:([a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\1))*$**

I have tried this regular expression but seems like repeating 2 chars not working.

Comment: `a-z and A-Z allowed` and `no capital letters is allowed` is conflicting; what have have you tried and what isn't specifically working?

Comment: Please don't add code in the comments, please add these details to your post by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69647705/edit) your existing post.

Comment: This question has been updated afterwards with additional data and a pattern, I voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern `^(?:([a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.\1))$` only matches a single character with `([a-zA-Z0-9])` so the assertion as no purpose.

The assertion `(?!.\1)` checks that the single captured value is not directly followed by  any char except a newline and a backreference to group 1, and as the `.\1` matches a single char before the backreference it does not guarantee 2 of the same repeating chars

---

You could assert not 2 of the same chars from the character class, and then match 6-9 chars.

```
^(?![a-zA-Z0-9]*([a-zA-Z0-9])\1)[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,9}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LNGxT0/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`\b(?:([a-zA-Z0-9])(?!\1)){6,9}\b`

Using `[a-zA-Z0-9]` already makes sure, special characters are not included, so you won't need `.` in the negative lookahead. Also, using `{6,9}` on the non capturing group `(?:)` limits the results to those with 6, 7, 8 or 9 characters.

If your 'word' starts at the beginning of each line and nothing follows your 'words' on each line, you can/should use `^` and `$` instead of the word [boundaries](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#anchors) `\b`, as you did in your example.